# Black-Scholes formula given arbitrary value of $S_{T}$

Tags: black-scholes

Is there a formula for Black and Scholes when we have expected payoff $\mathbb{E}[\max(se^{X}-K,0)]$ for $X$ having any normal distribution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X\sim N(m,v^2)$ be normally distributed. Then, for all strikes $K>0$ and $\omega\in\{-1,1\}$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\max\{\omega(e^X-K),0\}]=\omega e^{m+\frac{1}{2}v^2}\Phi\left(\omega\frac{m-\ln(K)+v^2}{v}\right)-\omega K\Phi\left(\omega\frac{m-\ln(K)}{v}\right),
\end{align*}
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf. The indicator $\omega$ is used to differentiate whether you have a call option ($\omega=1$) or a put option ($\omega=-1$).

It follows directly from integrating the log-normal density. [Brigo and Mercurio](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540221494) call this ``a useful calculation''.

The Black-Scholes formula is a special case of this equation where $m=\ln(S_0)+\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T$ and $v^2=\sigma^2T$.

Comment: what about the $s$?

Comment: @Nocturnal Note that $se^X=e^{\ln(s)+X}$. Thus, you simply add $\ln(s)$ to the mean $m$ but don't change the variance $v^2$. This is the reason why $m$ starts with $\ln(S_0)$ in the Black-Scholes case.